# Происхождение фамилии Пушкина

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Извините за детский вопрос. Но откуда взялась фамилия Пушкина? Сами пушки появились не столь давно. И почему от них произошла фамилия?

Answer (score 1):

Пушки появились как минимум раньше Пушкина. Это очевидно.

**Прозвище Пушка представляет собой пример именования по профессии. Пушкой на Руси называли либо артиллериста, либо рабочего на заводе, который занимался отливом пушек. Представители этой профессии были весьма уважаемы. Ведь российские пушки всегда пользовались спросом на мировом рынке. Еще в XVI веке в России отливали превосходные пушки.

Производителями артиллерийских орудий в то время были не только государевы пушкарские дворы, но и монастыри. К примеру, довольно крупное производство пушек велось в Соловецком монастыре и в Кирилло-Белозерском монастыре. Владели пушками и весьма их успешно применяли Донские и Запорожские казаки. Первое упоминание о применении пушек запорожскими казаками относится к 1516 году. А первая русская стальная пушка была изготовлена в 1860 году П. М. Обуховым, ставшая на тот момент одним из самых надежных огнестрельных орудий. Пушка, со временем получил фамилию Пушкин**

Окончание  - тут.

[Происхождение фамилии Пушкин](http://www.ufolog.ru/names/order/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD).